# Pasted view files do not get updated but copied code does in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I went through a very weird issue in Laravel 5 yesterday. I had a test project where I was playing around with things and I had my real project where I implement the stuff I am sure about.

I installed the [Smart Admin Theme](https://bootstraphunter.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-frontend-BSH01) in my demo project first to see how things go and when I was sure, I simply copied all the content of the public folder as well as the views folder and pasted them respectively.

I tried navigating to `auth/login` and it gave me an exception saying that view app not found in the login view which makes some sense because the original login view was extending the app view but I had removed all those files and this was the Smart Admin login page which did not extend app.

I went on digging but could not figure out anything. Later I installed a fresh copy of laravel but this time I did not copy paste the files but instead copied and pasted the content of the files into the login and register pages that come built in and this time it worked perfectly.

Can anyone tell me why the copied files did not work but when I just copied the content, it worked. I checked that both my demo project and it's folders have the same permissions especially the storage folder. I also tried clearing my cache but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no Laravel answer for this question. This is a strange behavior and can have many reasons. I would say a answer is hypothetical without seeing the error in action.